# How to run a docker image with all the arguments passed inline

Tags: docker

my docker file

```
ARG CUDA_VERSION=11.6.0
ARG OS_VERSION=20.04

FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA_VERSION}-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu${OS_VERSION}
LABEL maintainer="MoiiAI Inc"

WORKDIR /home/

ADD . .

ENV TRT_VERSION 8.4.1
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Setup user account
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
RUN groupadd -r -f -g ${gid} dev && useradd -o -r -l -u ${uid} -g ${gid} -ms /bin/bash dev
RUN usermod -aG sudo dev
RUN echo 'dev:moiiai' | chpasswd
RUN mkdir -p /home && chown -R dev:dev /home

# Required to build Ubuntu 20.04 without user prompts with DLFW container
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update CUDA signing key
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub

# Install requried libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    wget \
    git \
    pkg-config \
    sudo \
    ssh \
    libssl-dev \
    pbzip2 \
    pv \
    bzip2 \
    unzip \
    devscripts \
    lintian \
    fakeroot \
    dh-make \
    build-essential

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
RUN apt install -y vim

# Install python3
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      python3 \
      python3-pip \
      python3-dev \
      python3-wheel &&\
    cd /usr/local/bin &&\
    ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python &&\
    ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 pip;

# Install TensorRT
RUN if [ "${CUDA_VERSION}" = "10.2" ] ; then \
    v="${TRT_VERSION%.*}-1+cuda${CUDA_VERSION}" &&\
    apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    sudo apt-get install libnvinfer8=${v} libnvonnxparsers8=${v} libnvparsers8=${v} libnvinfer-plugin8=${v} \
        libnvinfer-dev=${v} libnvonnxparsers-dev=${v} libnvparsers-dev=${v} libnvinfer-plugin-dev=${v} \
        python3-libnvinfer=${v}; \
else \
    v="${TRT_VERSION}-1+cuda${CUDA_VERSION%.*}" &&\
    apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    sudo apt-get -y install libnvinfer8=${v} libnvonnxparsers8=${v} libnvparsers8=${v} libnvinfer-plugin8=${v} \
        libnvinfer-dev=${v} libnvonnxparsers-dev=${v} libnvparsers-dev=${v} libnvinfer-plugin-dev=${v} \
        python3-libnvinfer=${v}; \
fi

# Set environment and working directory
# ENV PATH="/home/dev/.local/bin:$PATH"
ENV PATH="/home/dev/.local/bin:$PATH"
ENV TRT_LIBPATH /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
ENV TRT_OSSPATH /home/TensorRT
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${TRT_OSSPATH}/build/out:${TRT_LIBPATH}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.6/compat"
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
ENV NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA "cuda>=10.2"

# Server.py
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install Cython
RUN pip3 install numpy==1.23.5
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/torch2trt &&\
    cd torch2trt && \
    python3 setup.py install

# 
USER dev
CMD ["python3","-u","server.py"]
```

my docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    container_name: server
    command: python3 -u server.py
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      SERVER_IP: 172.21.1.4
      SERVER_PORT: 9000
      CUDA_DRIVER_ID: "cuda:0"
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.1.4 # choose an IP address that is not already used on network
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              device_ids: ['0']
              capabilities: [gpu]

  client:
    build: ./client
    container_name: client
    command: python3 -u control.py
    depends_on:
      - server
    environment:
      SERVER_IP: 172.21.1.4
      SERVER_PORT: 9000
      PROJECT_NAME: "crowdcount"
      SERVER_NAME: "rocket-pc"
      INFLUX_DB_NAME: "ROCKET"
      CUDA_DRIVER_ID: "cuda:0" 
    networks:
      net:
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              device_ids: ['0']
              capabilities: [gpu]
networks:
  net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.21.0.0/16 # choose a subnet that is not already used on network
```

I am trying the run the docker image which got created using docker compose up and its pushed to artifact registry when i try pulling it on my local and do use a docker run command which is

```
docker run --gpus all --name server -p 9000:9000 \
  -e SERVER_IP=172.21.1.4 \
  -e SERVER_PORT=9000 \
  -e CUDA_DRIVER_ID="cuda:0" \
  --network net \
  --ip 172.21.1.4 \
  --device /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0 \
  us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/mipeople-f0294/python-infer/python-infer_server \
  python3 -u server.py
```

I am getting error either like this:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: user specified IP
address is supported only when connecting to networks
with user configured subnets. ERRO[0000] error waiting
for container: context canceled
```

This what I get when I do docker network inspect net where net is my network name:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "net",
        "Id": "d7fc56aa7d869c2f5ebcb12a5402fe565647542323ba93c323a8b5439e030466",
        "Created": "2023-04-25T15:33:05.454201322+05:30",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.21.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.21.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: How did you create your `net` network? The error message ("user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets") means you would have needed to include the `--subnet` option on your call to `docker network create`.

Comment: docker network create net command for creating it